# Find an algorithm to fully consume items with criteria and produce minimal result

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, constraint-satisfaction

So here are the prerequisites:

1. There are items to be consumed. Consider an item is just an object with a bunch of properties (e.g. size, weight), and there are tens or hundreds of properties.
2. Items have quantities. Example: Item_1 {size: 10, weight: 15} - quantity 3; Item_2 {size: 11, weight: 2} - quantity 15 etc.
3. There are consumers. Each consumer has an eligibility criteria, i.e. it can only consume items with specific properties.
4. Let's call a specific criteria for items a *type*. So for example {size > 10, weight < 5} is a type, and {weight = 0} is also a type.
5. Some consumers consume multiple types of items in specific proportions. For example, Consumer_1 consumes pairs of items, where first in a pair should have size > 10 and second in a pair should have weight = 10, and for each first item there should be exactly one item of the second (i.e. propoption is 1:1); Consumer_2 consumes only items of weight = 0, and since it only needs one type of item there's no proportion involved; and Consumer_3 accepts three types of items in proportion 1:2:1. Hope you get the idea.
6. Every consumer produces a number, that usually (but not always) depends on specific properties of the items it consumes. For better understanding, let's suppose the number represents a price, and it can be calculated as weight*5, for instance. But it can also depend on things not directly related to items, e.g. the day of week.
7. The number of consumers is around 20-30 if that is important.

The task is to consume all items (all their quantities) fully with the given set of consumers and produce a minimum/maximum result, which is a sum of all numbers that consumers produce.

This reminds me somehow of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which lead to thinking of a class of [combinatorial optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization) - which is obvious, because we need to match combinations of items to the consumers. But the difference is that (1) items need to be consumed fully (we guarantee that by having a fallback consumer that accepts any item), (2) the knapsack problem does not assume any predicates, i.e. a criteria for consumption.

More specifically, we map items to types and types to consumers. Then we can actually solve this as a linear optimization problem, but that proves to be slow and does not guarantee an optimal result, so I'm wondering if there is an algorithm that is better suited.